# How do I use the VSTS OAuth2 Bearer Token provided by the authorization routine?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am writing an MVC5 web application to allow me to query our Work Items in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

Having followed tutorials like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/integrate/quickstarts/work-item-quickstart) and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth#use-the-access-token) I have successfully created the application so that it will retrieve the Work Items I want using a Personal Access Token (PAT) that I created for the purposes of development. I have also, by closely following the sample available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/blob/master/OAuthWebSample/README.md), successfully created the entire OAuth2 process so that the user is taken to VSTS, asked to authorize my application, and then returned to my callback page. The callback URL correctly includes an Access Token, Refresh Token and so on for the user. So far, so good.

I store the user's Refresh Token in my database in their user record, along with the expiry date and time (so that I know to refresh the token if they try to access the application after their Access Token has expired).

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use the Access Token for the user instead of my own PAT in the C# code for querying VSTS. The code I'm using is below (it's virtually identical to that in the sample on GitHub that I linked to above), and it works fine, but as you can see it's using a PAT. How do I instead use the user's Access Token, which at the moment I'm just treating as a `string` when it's returned by the API (perhaps wrongly?).

```
public class GetFeatures
{
    readonly string _uri;
    readonly string _personalAccessToken;
    readonly string _project;

    public GetFeatures()
    {
        _uri = "https://myaccount.visualstudio.com";
        _personalAccessToken = "abc123xyz456"; //Obviously I've redacted my actual PAT
        _project = "My Project";
    }

    public List<VSTSFeatureModel> AllFeatures()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(_uri);
        string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;
        string project = _project;

        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);

        //create a wiql object and build our query
        Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
        {
            Query = "Select [State], [Title] " +
                    "From WorkItems " +
                    "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Feature' " +
                    "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
                    "And [System.State] <> 'Removed' " +
                    "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
        };

        //create instance of work item tracking http client
        using (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(uri, credentials))
        {
            //execute the query to get the list of work items in the results
            WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult = workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;

            //some error handling                
            if (workItemQueryResult.WorkItems.Count() != 0)
            {
                //...do stuff                   
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a huge amount of just guessing, since the VSTS .NET Client Library is very poorly documented, I discovered that `VssOAuthCredential` seems to be deprecated. I was able to get my code sample above working by replacing

```
VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken)
```

with

```
VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential credentials = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(AccessToken);
```

where AccessToken is a `string` containing the user's OAuth access token.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`VssOAuthCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples#authenticating-vsts) instead of `VssBasicCredential`.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case, but looking at the parameters that class requires I have no idea what values I should be passing, and it looks far too complicated. I have the Access Token for the user, surely all I need to do is include this in my requests to the API (as implied in the "Use The Access Token" section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth, albeit without saying how to do so with the .NET client library).

Answer (score 1):

That framework seems rather useless, haha...

I am currently working on a project for Backing Up VSTS Accounts and I'm doing all of it through HttpRequests to the REST API.

```
public List<int> GetItemIDs()
    {
        HttpClient client = auth.AuthenticateHTTP(new HttpClient());
        string content = $@"{{""query"": ""Select[System.Id] From WorkItems order by[System.CreatedDate] desc"" }}";
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string endpoint = "DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0";
        Uri requesturl = UriCombine(baseurl, endpoint);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(requesturl, stringContent).Result;
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryResponse>(result);
        return json.workItems.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
    }

public List<string> ListToString200(List<int> ids) //Writes all IDs into comma seperated strings of up to 200 IDs and puts them into a List.
        {
            List<string> idStrings = new List<string>();

            if (ids.Count > 200)
            {
                while (ids.Count > 200)
                {
                    List<int> t = new List<int>();
                    var IDs = ids.Take(200);
                    ids.Remove(200);
                    foreach (var item in IDs)
                    {
                        t.Add(item);
                    }

                    var ID = t.ConvertAll(element => element.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a},{b}");
                    idStrings.Add(ID);
                }
            }
            else if (ids.Count > 0)
            {
                var ID = ids.ConvertAll(element => element.ToString()).Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}");
                idStrings.Add(ID);
            }

            return idStrings;
        }


private List<WorkItem> GetAllWorkItems()
        {
            List<int> ids = GetItemIDs();
            List<WorkItemsContainer> Responses = new List<WorkItemsContainer>();
            List<WorkItem> ResultList = new List<WorkItem>();

            List<string> idStrings = ListToString200(ids);

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                auth.AuthenticateHTTP(client);

                foreach (var item in idStrings)
                {
                    WorkItemsContainer WorkItem = new WorkItemsContainer();

                    string featurePath = $"DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={item}&$expand=all&api-version=1.0";
                    Uri requestUri = Authenticator.UriCombine(baseurl, featurePath);
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
                    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    result = result.Replace("System.", "System");

                    WorkItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkItemsContainer>(result);
                    Responses.Add(WorkItem);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in Responses)
            {
                foreach (var x in item.value.ToList<WorkItem>())
                {
                    WorkItemsToJsonFile(x);
                    ResultList.Add(x);
                }
            }
            return ResultList;
        }
```

Much easier with fixed logins, don't need the Oauth2 although, doing OAuth2 manually isn't that much harder, just turn the token into a bearer authentication header...

Comment: I wish I'd started out just using the REST APIs, but I was invested with the .NET client library by the time I posted my question! I got it working in the end - see the answer I posted. Also, I was keen to use OAuth because I'll have multiple users accessing my application and I want them to be reading/writing from/to the API as themselves. However, if you can tell me how to successfully pass the OAuth acces token in an Ajax call (can do it with the PAT, can't figure out the access token) you'd be my hero!

Comment: Never heard of PAT tbh :(
In C#, using HttpClient it's `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");`